# How to use TYPO3 v10 Extension Builder to enhance pages

Tags: extbase, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to create an extension that will enhance the pages with additional fields. Since there are a lot of relations and properties I wanted to use the Extension Builder which tells in the documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/stable/Developer/ExtendingModels.html) that if I would like to extend an model, I have to: **You have to enter the class name (not the model name!) of the model** in the field.

So now the question is: What is the class name for pages? The class name for Frontend Users is: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser. This one is mentioned in all descriptions.

Where can I find the class name for pages?

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answers your question. But if you want to add new fields to page property you can follow
https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/how-to-extend-typo3-database-tables-with-new-fields/

Comment: Hey Vikram, thx for your answer. I know how to enhance tables basically. And your link is definitely a nice enhancement at this point. But as you told, it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: It quite unlikely that all things would have it's own class. For pages the link I shared is the way to add fields to page

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with that. But this way I break continues development with the extension buider. And Extension Builder does much coding for you, if you are able to use it.

So lets go the long way.